# Tkinter trying simple math using GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Trying to make a very basic addition calculator with python and tkinter.  It gives me an error:

```
    btresult = Button(window, text = "Compute Sum", command = self.result).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = E)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to connect this.

```
from tkinter import *

class addCalculator:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Add Calculator")

        Label(window, text = "First Number: ").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Label(window, text = "Second Number: ").grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.number1Var = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable = self.number1Var, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.number2Var = StringVar()
        Entry(window, textvariable = self.number2Var, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        self.resultVar = StringVar()
        lblresult = Label(window, textvariable = self.result.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)

        btresult = Button(window, text = "Compute Sum", command = self.result).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = E)

        def result(self):
            resultVar = self.resultVar.set(eval(self.number1Var.get()) + eval(self.number2Var.get()))
            return resultVar

        window.mainloop()

addCalculator()
```

Comment: Yeah so it still does not work.  THe result is not printing to the screen.  I've tried several different tuts but when I modify them for this simple exercise I cant get any result to print.  something is wrong with either my function or the variable being called.  I think.

Comment: Create an instance of the class `addCalculator` (eg, myinstance = addCalculator()`. Unindent your `result` function. Put `window.mainloop()` in a function, then call that function with the instance

Answer (score 3):

On the previous line (`lblresult = ...`), you forgot to close your opened parentheses. Python interprets this (both that line and the next line, `btresult = ...`) as one whole line of code, but obviously this can't work with your code, hence the `SyntaxError`

Comment: Good answer. In general, whenever you get a `SyntaxError` on a line that can't possibly be invalid, check above for any un-closed parens, brackets, braces, triple-quotes, etc.

Comment: So after cleaning this up a bit, I still do not see the result label(field), and it does not get filled with the result.

Comment: @ohvonbraun I am not experienced with Tkinter, so I can't help you there. Are there any other errors though?

Comment: @ohvonbraun The code you've posted has many problems and errors, and does not run, even after fixing the close paren problem.  If you've cleaned it up enough so it runs, and you still have a question, please post your updated code.  I could clean it up for you, but then you and I would be working with different code, and it would be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my own way.  I tried to stay faithful to the original question but the code needed a lot of clean up.  There was lots of little odds and ends to fix, but i think the main problem was the method of passing the integers to the function.  I also changed the original lblresult from a label to an Entry widget.  Im still new at Python but getting better.  I found this question while looking for a similar answer and solving this also solved my problem. Thanks!  Code below:

```
from Tkinter import *

class addCalculator:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Add Calculator")

        def result(z1,z2):
            biz=z1+z2
            lblresult.delete(0,END)
            lblresult.insert(0,biz)
            return

        Label1 = Label(window, text = "First Number: ").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Label2 = Label(window, text = "Second Number: ").grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.number1Var = IntVar()
        Entry1 = Entry(window, textvariable = self.number1Var, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        self.number2Var = IntVar()
        Entry2 = Entry(window, textvariable = self.number2Var, justify = RIGHT).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        Label3 = Label(window, text = "Result: ").grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        lblresult = Entry(window, justify = RIGHT)
        lblresult.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)

        btresult = Button(window,text="Compute Sum",command=lambda:result(self.number1Var.get(),self.number2Var.get()))
        btresult.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = E)

        window.mainloop()

addCalculator()
```